# mapping complex data to Objects using Java8 Stream

Tags: java, file, collections, stream

I have a text file that has a set of records as follows:

```
START
PARENT1 dataX dataY
CHILD1 dataA dataB
CHILD2 dataC DataD
PARENT2 dataJ dataK
CHILD1 dataE dataF
END
```

I want to create a List objects. each PARENT should have all the child objects as a List.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please post that first. What is your domain model to handle this?

Comment: You could do it with a `reduce` or `collect` where at each iteration you check if the current element is a parent. If it is, you add it to the list, and if it's not, you add the child to the last parent in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the `List` of parents with children. I defined classes `Parent` and `Child`. A `Parent` has children - defined as a collection `List<Child>`. The program iterates over the lines of the input file and processes each line. An external collection `List<Parent>`, defined as a static variable, stores all the parents.

The example program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class ComplexObjects {
    private static List<Parent> parents;
    private static Parent parent;
    private static boolean startFlag;
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("complex_data.txt");
        Files.lines(path)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .forEach(line -> processLine(line));
        System.out.println(parents);
    }
    private static void processLine(String line) {
        if (line.startsWith("START")) {
            startFlag = true;
            parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("PARENT")) {
            // store the parent with children
            // create a new parent
            if (startFlag) {
                startFlag = false;
            }
            else {
                parents.add(parent);
            }
            parent = new Parent(line);
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("CHILD")) {
            // create a new child
            // add to the parent
            String [] tokens = line.split(" ");
            parent.addChild(new Child(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]));
        }
        else if (line.startsWith("END")) {
            parents.add(parent); // store the last parent
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invaid file data: " + line);
        }
    }
}
class Parent {
    private String data;
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
    public Parent(String s) {
        data = s;
    }
    public void addChild(Child c) {
        children.add(c);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return data + ": " + children.toString();
    }
}
class Child {
    private String name;
    private String dataA;
    private String dataB;
    public Child(String s, String a, String b) {
        name = s;
        dataA = a;
        dataB = b;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + dataA + ", " + dataB;
    }
}
```

**Example input file - complex_data.txt:**

```
START
PARENT1 dataX dataY
CHILD1 dataA dataB
CHILD2 dataC DataD
PARENT2 dataJ dataK
CHILD1 dataE dataF
PARENT3 dataZ dataZ
END
```

**Output:**

```
[PARENT1 dataX dataY: [CHILD1: dataA, dataB, CHILD2: dataC, DataD], PARENT2 dataJ dataK: [CHILD1: dataE, dataF], PARENT3 dataZ dataZ: []]
```